# android opengl-es spritesheet display number

Tags: android, opengl-es, spritesheet

Whats the best way to display numbers on android with opengl using a spritesheet?

I like to display the number "294" using the spritesheet:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv5Zh.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for.

- First I downloaded a game font: http://www.fontspace.com/triforce89/pipe-dream
- Second I found a tool which made me a spritesheet of a font: http://www.lmnopc.com/bitmapfontbuilder/

In my code then I just can write normal text and I can get the ascii codes of each character to calculate where its position on the generated spritesheet.

Here is a fragment of my used code where I get the acsii codes of my "text":

```
    byte[] ascii = new byte[0];
    try {
        ascii = text.getBytes("US-ASCII");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```